# How can I add callouts to a LogLogPlot and control their positioning?

Tags: plotting, labeling, logarithmic-scale

I made this plot

```
LogLogPlot[{n!, 2^n, n^2, n Log[n], n, Log[n]}, {n, 1, 1000}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Elements", "Operations"}, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend["Expressions", LegendLabel -> "Functions", 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> None] &)], 
  Background -> None]
```

[image]

Now I want to replace the legend with callouts labeling the traces, but I'm having some trouble:

```
funs = Callout[#, ToString@#, Above] & /@ {n!, 2^n, n^2, n Log[n], n, Log[n]};
LogLogPlot[Evaluate@funs, {n, E, 1000}, 
Frame -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"Elements", "Operations"}, 
Background -> None, 
PlotRange -> {{E, 1000}}]
```

[image]

I'd like the callouts to be placed next to the function it calls out, not on top. Seems like none of the argument values for positioning the callout  (Before, After, Above, Below) get this right.

Comment: Your code as posted (the second one) gives an error  `Plot::invpr: Value of option PlotRange is not compatible with the option ScalingFunctions -> {{Log,Exp},{Log,Exp}}`

Comment: @Nasser fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "having trouble" you mean the formating part. In this case, this produces better result. Using `TraditionalForm` in place of `ToString`

```
 funs=Callout[#,TraditionalForm@#,Above]&/@{n!,2^n,n^2,n Log[n],n,Log[n]};
```

Now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also these work

```
funs=Callout[#,#,Above]&/@{n!,2^n,n^2,n Log[n],n,Log[n]};
funs=Callout[#,Text@#,Above]&/@{n!,2^n,n^2,n Log[n],n,Log[n]};
```

Just do not use `ToString`

Answer (score 5):

Positioning callouts can be tricky, but there is a lot more positioning control available than the predefined values `Before`, `After`, `Above`, and `Below`. It is possible to explicitly and separately set the both label point and the anchor point. I will show you how to do that.

First, let's get separate definitions for the functions and their labels.

```
funcs = {n!, 2^n, n^2, n Log[n], n, Log[n]};
lbls = HoldForm /@ funcs;
```

Now let's make a preview plot so we can extract the end points of the function traces.

```
preview = 
  LogLogPlot[Evaluate@funcs, {n, E, 1000}, PlotRange -> {{E, 1000}, {1, 1000}}];
endPts = Exp[Last @@@ Cases[preview, Line[__], ∞]];
```

Now let's build the callouts. I am not certain what you mean by "callouts to be placed next to the function it calls[out]", but because of the way your functions fill the plot viewport, I have chosen to place the anchor points at the end of the traces and the function labels to the right of and a little below the end of the traces. I hope this interpretation is close to what you have in mind.

```
traces = 
  MapThread[
    Callout[#1, #2, #3 + {.125 #3[[1]], -.01 #3[[2]]}, #3] &, 
    {funcs, lbls, endPts}];
```

Note that the 3rd argument to `Callout` sets the position of label and the 4th argument sets the position of the anchor point.

```
LogLogPlot[Evaluate@traces, {n, E, 1000},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, 1000}},
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Scaled[.075]}, {Automatic, Scaled[.05]}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Elements", "Operations"},
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: plot]