# Change the vertical order of automatic PlotLabels without changing the horizontal positioning

Tags: plotting, labeling

I recently updated to Mathematica 11.2, and I very much like the automatic `PlotLabels` feature that I discovered.  However, it picks a somewhat silly ordering when the data I'm plotting cuts off at different x-locations.  Say I have data that looks something like this:

```
slopes = Table[i Round[Abs[Sin[i]], 0.1], {i, 1, 5, 0.2}];
mydata = Table[Select[Table[{x, 1 + slope * x^2}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}], #1[[2]] < 100 &],
   {slope, slopes}];
```

If I just `ListPlot` it, Mathematica does something smart about plot label vertical positioning which I haven't managed to recreate manually:

```
ListPlot[mydata, PlotLabels -> slopes, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: smart PlotLabels]

However, the ordering is all off; I want to order them by the slope, not by the y-value at the location where my data happened to cut off.  So I tried using `Callout` instead, with a manually specified anchor position:

```
ListPlot[Map[Callout[#1[[1]], #1[[2]], Automatic, 5] &, 
    Transpose[{mydata, slopes}]], ImageSize -> Large]
```

This gives the horrendous-looking

[image: bad callout]

Okay, fine, I can give it a position manually.  But `10` and `{10, After}` both give identical, very bad results:

[image: manual x position]

---

What I want, from most important to least important (but preferably all of them):

1. the labels should not overlap and should not be cut off
2. the labels should have a pointer to some point on the curve
3. the labels should be in slope-order, or, more precisely, the order that the data has at a particular x-position that I specify
4. the labels should all be along the right side of the plot, the axis should not extend past the end of the data

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2105/12

Comment: Also, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161744/3066 might be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Callout` with explicit positions for labels in the setting of  `PlotLabels` combined with manual reordering of input data:

```
slopes = Sort@Table[i Round[Abs[Sin[i]], 0.1], {i, 1, 5, 0.2}];
mydata = Table[Select[Table[{x, 1 + slope * x^2}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}], #1[[2]] <= 100 &],
   {slope, slopes}];

ordering ={1,2,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,11,12,3,4,10,9,8,7,6,5};
mydataordered = mydata[[ordering]];
slopesordered = slopes[[ordering]];
xpos = 12;
yrange = {5, 100};

ListPlot[mydataordered,
 PlotLabels -> MapIndexed[Callout[#,{xpos, Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, Length@mydata}, yrange]}, 
     mydataordered[[All,-1]][[#2[[1]]]], 
     LeaderSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 0}, {30, 0 Degree}}]&, slopesordered], 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic,200}, { Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Use `xpos = 11; yrange={20, 100};` to get

[image]

Alternatively, use

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Callout[#, slopesordered[[#2[[1]]]], 
    {xpos, Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, Length @ mydata}, yrange]}, 
     mydataordered[[All,-1]][[#2[[1]]]], 
  LeaderSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 0}, {30, 0 Degree}}]&, mydataordered],
ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 200}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

to get the same result as above.

**Update:** An alternative layout for the `Callout`s:

```
combined = Transpose[{mydata, slopes}];
{top, left} = Pick[combined, #[[1, -1, 1]]  < 9.9 & /@ combined, #]&/@{True, False};
{datatop, slopestop} = Transpose[SortBy[top, #[[1,-1,1]]&]];
{dataleft, slopesleft} = Transpose[SortBy[left, #[[1,-1,-1]]&]];
dL = MapIndexed[Callout[#, slopesleft[[#2[[1]]]], 
 {11, Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, Length @ dataleft}, {30, 90}]}, dataleft[[All,-1]][[#2[[1]]]], 
 LeaderSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 0}, {10, 0 Degree}}]&, dataleft];
dT = MapIndexed[Callout[#, slopestop[[#2[[1]]]], 
 {Rescale[#2[[1]],{1, Length @ datatop}, {1, 12}], 110}, datatop[[All, -1]][[#2[[1]]]], 
 LeaderSize -> {{Automatic, Automatic, 0}, {10, 90 Degree}}]&, datatop];

ListPlot[Join[dL,dT], ImagePadding -> {{Automatic,200},{ Automatic, 100}}, 
 ImageSize->800, PlotRangeClipping->False]
```

[image]