# How to get Callout and Text[...,Offset[...]] to use the same coordinate system in Mathematica 12?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, labeling, inset

I could have sworn this worked in a previous version of Mathematica, but when I transcribe the coordinates used to label text offsets, I get errors like `Callout::copos: {{{0.193964,-2.26836+3.14159 I},{0,0.5}}} is not a valid position for the placement of callouts.`

Here is an example:

The code

```
ListLogLogPlot[Table[a + {1, 1, 1}, {a, {0, 0.1, 0.2, .3, .4, 5}}], 
 PlotLabels -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}]
% /. Text[x___] :> (Print[Defer[Text][x]]; Text[x])
```

gives
[image]
and
[image: text]

But if I copy the offset position and use it as a base position in `Callout`, then I get errors:

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 Callout[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, 
  "a", {{1.2140528054201887`, -0.1034814269216698`}, {0, 0.5}}]]
```

gives

```
Callout::copos: {{{0.193964,-2.26836+3.14159 I},{0,0.5}}} is not a valid position for the placement of callouts.
```

I'm pretty sure this worked in a previous version of Mathematica.  My question is, how do I automatically transform the textual positions into arguments that `Callout` will handle correctly.  (Ideally in a way that's parametric in whether I generated the graphic from `ListLogPlot` or `ListPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot`, though I do have access to which one I used to generate it.)

By the way, my full code is at https://github.com/mit-plv/reification-by-parametricity/blob/d1bc17cf99a66e0268f655e28cdb375e712cd831/reification-by-parametricity-graphs.wls ; the thing I'm trying to do (and which was working in a previous version of Mathematica) is to control the order of the plot labels so that they match the order that I gave the data in.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), particularly considering your last point about ordering plot labels. Could you expand on the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than on your attempted solution? There may well be a more direct way of accomplishing what you want. It would be best if you included some sample code showcasing the unwanted behavior, and then described the desired behavior as well.

Comment: The actual question is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162623/change-the-vertical-order-of-automatic-plotlabels-without-changing-the-horizonta , but I want to not have to rely on Mathematica to generate the relevant vertical and horizontal spacing for me, so that I don't have to hand-code it.  I want to specify only the ordering of the data.