# How do I determine the scaling function on the axes of Plot-like functions?

Tags: plotting

I want to define a function like

```
AxisScaling[Plot] = {Identity, Identity};
AxisScaling[LogPlot] = {Log, Identity};
AxisScaling[LogLogPlot] = {Log, Log};
AxisScaling[ListPlot] = {Identity, Identity};
AxisScaling[ListLogPlot] = {Log, Identity};
AxisScaling[ListLogLogPlot] = {Log, Log};
```

except more programmatic.  Looking at the manual suggests that I might want to somehow determine the default value for `ScalingFunctions` for each of these, and looking at `G @@ ListPlot[{1}]` vs `G @@ ListLogPlot[{1}]` vs `G @@ ListLogLogPlot[{1}]` suggests that I might want to look for `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` in `Ticks`, or perhaps at `Method->CoordinatesToolOptions->DisplayFunction` (or perhaps `CopiedValueFunction`?).  What's the right way to extract this information?  (The ultimate reason I want this information is for [How to get Callout and Text[...,Offset[...]] to use the same coordinate system in Mathematica 12?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237774/how-to-get-callout-and-text-offset-to-use-the-same-coordinate-system-i), to transform the coordinates from the `Text` in a plot output into coordinates I can input into `Callout`, so if it helps `AxisScaling` can take in the output of the plot function instead of the function itself.

Comment: I need to understand your objective. Are you trying to find out what scaling has been applied to a plot or just what the function name was that made the plot? The function name tells you the form of the axis used in a plot.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what function to apply to the coordinates used in `Text` inside a `Graphics` object so that I can pass them to `Callout` inside the plot-function that generated the `Graphics` object and have them show in the correct place.  I eventually went for `("CopiedValueFunction"/.("CoordinatesToolOptions"/.(Method/.Options[G])))` for `G` the graphics object, but I'm open to better solutions if there are more correct ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that defining

```
AxisScaling[G_]:=("CopiedValueFunction"/.("CoordinatesToolOptions"/.(Method/.Options[G])))
```

works pretty well when I pass the output plot as the argument to `AxisScaling`.