# How can I remove extra parentheses in a plot callout?

Tags: plotting, labeling

This question is motivated by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161741/how-can-i-add-callouts-to-a-loglogplot-and-control-their-positioning) and its answers.

Firstly, I wish to display "O(x)" instead of "x" as the callout labels. When I do this

```
lbls = Map[HoldForm["O(" #1 ")"] &, funcs];
```

I get double parenthesis for the fourth element. How can I avoid this extra parenthesis without altering the formatting style?

Secondly, How can I display only the callout labels without the callout lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `HoldForm[]` on the head instead:

```
funs = Callout[#, TraditionalForm[HoldForm[O][#]], Above] & /@
       {n!, 2^n, n^2, n Log[n], n, Log[n]};

LogLogPlot[Evaluate @ funs, {n, E, 1000}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {E, 1000}]
```

[image: with nice labels]

As m_goldberg notes in his answer to the linked question, the default layout might not be entirely satisfactory; which necessitates manual position tweaking. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Is it not possible to remove the callout lines?

Comment: Try `CalloutStyle -> Transparent`.

Comment: You can use Labeled instead of Callout. No other changes are needed.